# WPF glass window with no border and no resize out of focus

Tags: c#, wpf, aero, aero-glass

I am trying to create a Aero glass **borderless** and **non-resizable** WPF window using the `DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow` method from the `DmwAPI`. However, for some strange reason the glass color of this window appears as if the window is *out of focus*. As you can see in the next three images, the normal windows with borders (*e.g figure 1 and 2*) work just fine and react as expected (dark blue in focus, whitish when out of focus (= non active)).

[image: DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow with ToolWindow]
[image: DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow with ToolWindow out of focus]

The borderless window with resizing allowed, shows the same behavior:

[image: DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow with borderless but resizable window]

The **non-resizable borderless** window however will always look as if it is out of focus (as you can see in the last *figure 3*) both when it is active and non-active. It always looks whitish:

[image: DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow with borderless and non-resizable window]

This is some example code of how I set the glass style:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
    ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;

    Height = 200;

    Background = Brushes.Transparent;
    Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
}
void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var windowInteropHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
    var handle = windowInteropHelper.Handle;
    var mainWindowSrc = HwndSource.FromHwnd(handle);

    if (mainWindowSrc != null)
        if (mainWindowSrc.CompositionTarget != null)
            mainWindowSrc.CompositionTarget.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
    var glassParams = new DwmApi.DwmBlurbehind
    {
        dwFlags = DwmApi.DwmBlurbehind.DWM_BB_ENABLE,
        fEnable = true,
        hRegionBlur = IntPtr.Zero
    };

    IntPtr dis = new IntPtr(2);
    DwmApi.DwmSetWindowAttribute(mainWindowSrc.Handle,
                DwmApi.DwmWindowAttribute.DWMWA_LAST,
                dis,
                sizeof(uint));

    DwmApi.DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow(
        handle,
        glassParams
        );
}
```

I tried focusing the window, but that doesn't seem to affect the behavior. Any ideas or pointers on how to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't worked much in dwm apis so I may be wrong but I think the default dwm rendering policy is using WindowStyle to figure out rendering. If you disable that policy, it behaves as you'd expect it to.

Add the following bit to fix your blues xD

```
const int DWMWA_NCRENDERING_POLICY = 2;
int DWMNCRP_DISABLED = 2;

DwmSetWindowAttribute(hwnd, DWMWA_NCRENDERING_POLICY, ref DWMNCRP_DISABLED, sizeof(int));
```

For details of this voodoo, please check the following resources:

[DwmSetWindowAttribute function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969524.aspx)

[DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969530.aspx)

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="dwm.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"/>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace dwm
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        [DllImport("dwmapi.dll", PreserveSig = false)]
        public static extern void DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow(IntPtr hwnd, ref DwmBlurbehind blurBehind);

        [DllImport("dwmapi.dll", PreserveSig = true)]
        private static extern int DwmSetWindowAttribute(IntPtr hwnd, int attr, ref int attrValue, int attrSize);

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnSourceInitialized(e);

            var bb = new DwmBlurbehind
            {
                dwFlags = CoreNativeMethods.DwmBlurBehindDwFlags.DwmBbEnable,
                Enabled = true
            };

            WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
            Background = Brushes.Transparent;
            ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
            WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;

            Focus();

            var hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;

            HwndSource.FromHwnd(hwnd).CompositionTarget.BackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;

            DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow(hwnd, ref bb);

            const int dwmwaNcrenderingPolicy = 2;
            var dwmncrpDisabled = 2;

            DwmSetWindowAttribute(hwnd, dwmwaNcrenderingPolicy, ref dwmncrpDisabled, sizeof(int));
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct DwmBlurbehind
        {
            public CoreNativeMethods.DwmBlurBehindDwFlags dwFlags;
            public bool Enabled;
            public IntPtr BlurRegion;
            public bool TransitionOnMaximized;
        }

        public static class CoreNativeMethods
        {
            public enum DwmBlurBehindDwFlags
            {
                DwmBbEnable = 1,
                DwmBbBlurRegion = 2,
                DwmBbTransitionOnMaximized = 4
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Screenshot with focus**

[image: Screenshot with focus]

**Screenshot without focus**

[image: Screenoshot without focus]

**Test Environment**

OS: Windows 8 - x64

Theme: Standard windows

Comment: I have tried this before and tried it again now, but no luck unfortunately:


`        IntPtr dis = new IntPtr(2);
            DwmApi.DwmSetWindowAttribute(mainWindowSrc.Handle,
                                      DwmApi.DwmWindowAttribute.DWMWA_NCRENDERING_POLICY,
                                       dis,
                                      sizeof(uint));`

Comment: Will need to see more code as I can reproduce your issue exactly as you describe and fix it with the code above. Perhaps we can switch to a room discussion. I'm online pretty much all working days (GMT+1) in WPF room

Comment: I haven't looked at your code yet, but I think I found your problem. You're using `IntPtr` and I'm using `ref int`. Indeed my code fails to work if I use your method signature. Try switching to `ref int` and see if it works for you.

Comment: @StevenHouben I just used your entire code bit changing the method signature to `ref int` and your code works as well.

Comment: Thanks, it works! One more thing: any idea on how to prevent the window from going out of focus? I need it to behave similar to the taskbar.

Comment: No sorry, not off the top of my head right now. Will have to research.